# Which one is correct: "do something via Google Meet video call" or "do something via a Google Meet video call"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can you please tell me which one is correct: *do something via Google Meet video call* or *do something via a Google Meet video call*? For example:

> I can show you how to install the software via (**a**) Google Meet video call.

I've noticed that when the type of video call isn't specified, then *a* is omitted. But what about when the medium of a video call is specified, like in my sentence, is the indefinite article needed?

Comment: Using “via a” is awkward to say, so “via” is often used without “a”. Using “a” would specify that only one video call would take place; leaving it out leaves the number of calls open and just specifies a method.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence needs an **article**, either **a** or **the**, because the **noun** is *call*, which is used here as both a **countable** and a **singular** noun.

The principle at play is that singular countable nouns *always* need some sort of article.

To understand why the noun *call* is singular and countable, see [here](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/call#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_call_2).

To understand why such nouns always need an article, see [here](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/count_and_noncount_nouns/count_noncount_nouns_with_articles_adjectives.html#:%7E:text=A%20countable%20noun%20always%20takes,a%20guest%20in%20our%20home.).

The correct sentence is: *I can show you how to install the software via **a** Google Meet video call.*

Comment: "They will arrive via automobile."   Correct or incorrect?   And, "they will arrive via a car"?  "they will arrive via the car"?

Comment: (MW use example for via:  "Parking is available via seasonal permit for both residents and non-residents, or a $35 daily pass.")